# IntPtr to array of struct

Tags: vb.net, struct, structure, intptr

I am calling a native API through VB.Net passing a pointer to array of structures (RootCausesInfo) which in turn contains pointer to array of structures (RepairInfoEx). The native signature of the API is on [MSDN - NdfDiagnoseIncident](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309556%28VS.85%29.aspx)

The structure definition and PInvoke call that I used in VB.Net are:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure RepairInfoEx
    Public repair As RepairInfo
    Public repairRank As UShort
End Structure

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure RootCauseInfo
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
    Public pwszDescription As String
    Public rootCauseID As GUID
    Public rootCauseFlags As UInteger
    Public networkInterfaceID As GUID
    Public pRepairs As IntPtr
    Public repairCount As UShort
End Structure

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("ndfapi.dll", EntryPoint:="NdfDiagnoseIncident", CallingConvention:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Function NdfDiagnoseIncident(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()> ByVal Handle As System.IntPtr, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute()> ByRef RootCauseCount As UInteger, ByRef RootCauses As IntPtr, ByVal dwWait As Integer, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer
    End Function
```

The code that calls the above API is:

```
    Dim rcInfoPtrToArray As IntPtr = Nothing
    Dim intRootCauseInfoSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(RootCauseInfo))
    Dim intRepairInfoExSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(RepairInfoEx))
    If HResult = 0 Then
        HResult = NdfDiagnoseIncident(ndfHandle, rootCauseCount, rcInfoPtrToArray, NativeConstants.INFINITE, 0)
        If rootCauseCount > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To rootCauseCount - 1 
                Dim rootCausePtr As IntPtr = New IntPtr(rcInfoPtrToArray.ToInt32 + intRootCauseInfoSize * i)
                Dim causeObj As RootCauseInfo = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(rootCausePtr, GetType(RootCauseInfo)), RootCauseInfo)
                Dim pRepairs(causeObj.repairCount) As IntPtr
                Marshal.Copy(causeObj.pRepairs, pRepairs, 0, causeObj.repairCount)
                For Each pRepair As IntPtr In pRepairs 
                    Dim repair As RepairInfoEx = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(pRepair, GetType(RepairInfoEx)), RepairInfoEx)
                    MsgBox(repair.repair.pwszDescription)
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
```

When the API call returns, it populates the rcInfoPtrToArray with a pointer address to RootCauseInfo structures. I get each instance of RootCauseInfo with following line:

```
Dim rootCausePtr As IntPtr = New IntPtr(rcInfoPtrToArray.ToInt32 + intRootCauseInfoSize * i)
```

This works fine. I use similar IntPtr arithmetic to navigate to individual elements of RepairInfoEx instances:

```
Dim repairInfoExPtr As IntPtr = New IntPtr(causeObj.pRepairs.ToInt32 + intRepairInfoExSize * j)
```

When I get to converting repairInfoExPtr to RepairInfoEx structure with following line, it again works fine for first instance of RepairInfoEx with j=0:

```
Dim repair As RepairInfoEx = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(repairInfoExPtr, GetType(RepairInfoEx)), RepairInfoEx)
```

But in the next iteration of j=1, the pointer seems screwed up and I get "Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown." error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like memory parts destroyed. Do you lock the data that is referenced by the pointers against moving by Garbage Collector? like you have to when using the interface to read and play WAV-files:         hmem(i) = GlobalAlloc(0, m_BufferSize)
        pmem(i) = GlobalLock(hmem(i))
        hhmem = GCHandle.Alloc(hmem, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        hpmem = GCHandle.Alloc(pmem, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        hHdr = GCHandle.Alloc(hdr, GCHandleType.Pinned)